# Storing numbers from a specific string in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am reading a .csv file in python and inside the CSV there are a bunch of strings of the form `"formula=0.23","formula=0.5"....` in different locations with different values. There are also other things of this form in the file like `"data=1"` and `"ID=2"` etc... I want to make python store these values in a list in a way to say `"when you find the word "formula="` store the number that you see after it. I tried `"?="` to match the string however I can't fix the counter that will read the string and match. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. Show some sample input and the result you're trying to get. Also show the code you tried to write -- we'll help you fix it, but we won't write it for you from scratch.

Comment: Use ```str.startswith()```  to identify your strings, use ```str.find()``` to find the index of the equals sign, slice the string using that index (+1), store the result.  No need for a regular expression.  [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)